# What does ' >>> ' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of javascript code that I am trying to understand

```
return ( n >>> 0 ) * 2.34e10;
```

So what does >>> mean?

And thanks in advance ... this is my first question on SO

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a [zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3e.3e.3e_(Zero-fill_right_shift)). This won't do anything to positive whole numbers or 0, but it does funny things on negative numbers (because the [most significant bit changes to zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)).

```
 2 >>> 0 === 2
 1 >>> 0 === 1
 0 >>> 0 === 0
-1 >>> 0 === 4294967295
-2 >>> 0 === 4294967294
-3 >>> 0 === 4294967293
```

It should be noted (thanks Andy!) that bit shifting in JavaScript [converts the arguments to signed 32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Summary) before doing the shifting. Therefore `>>> 0` essentially does a `Math.floor` on positive numbers:

```
1.1 >>> 0 === 1
1.9 >>> 0 === 1
```

Comment: I wanted to +1, but I felt compelled to perform a minor edit first ;-) You could also expand on what it will do to positive floats, if you wanted to :-)

Comment: @Andy Very appreciated, and good point.

Comment: Brilliant!!... Thanks a lot Skilldrick, Andy E and acqu13sce. Thanks also for the references.

Comment: This operation is actually the only bitwise operation in JavaScript that is **unsigned**

Comment: `>>>` is unsigned right shift, `>>` is signed right shift. The former converts the RHS using ToUint32, which does what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bitwise operator. It means shift n by 0 bits. Not sure what it's trying to do in the instance you show.

```
a >>> b  // shift a by b bits to the right, padding with zeros
```

Comment: `(a >>> 0)` is used to coerce `a` to a 32 bit unsigned integer.