# What do "num & 8", "num >> 8" and "num >> 8 & 64" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am having a hard time googling because of the symbols.

What do `num & 8`, `num >> 8` and `num >> 8 & 64` mean in javascript?

Comment: Don't look for the trees. Look for the forest. In this case, you are looking for "javascript operators" (of which there are numerous tables, from whence the correct operator can be looked up).

Comment: For links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654057/where-would-i-use-a-bitwise-operator-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324761/bit-tweaking-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734451/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do ">>" and "<<" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997909/what-do-and-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

They are [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

to get the hundreds digit [num]->[/ 100]->[% 10]

To extract bits, use the [&] object to mask out the bit you're interested in, then optionally bit shift with [>>].

For instance, to get bit 3 (counting from *right* starting with zero) [num]->[& 8]->[>> 3].

If you just want to use the calculation to control a logic object (like if or a ggate), you can skip the bit shift.

These are really not Max-specific questions, they are fundamental DP techniques.

Answer (score 1):

**Shift left <<**

The following expression means, shift 2 binary numbers to left:

```
alert( 1 << 2 );
```

So binary this is (I'll take 8 bit for example), shift the bits to left, 2 places

```
00000001 = 1
00000010 = 2
00000100 = 4
```

**Shift right >>**

The following expression means, shift 2 binary numbers to left:

```
alert( 255 >> 2 );
```

So binary this is (I'll take 8 bit for example), shift the bits to right, 2 places

```
11111111 = 255
01111111 = 127
00111111 = 63
```

**AND operator &**

That's the and operator

So you got the following rules:

```
11110011 = 243
01001111 = 79
01000011 = 67 = RESULT
```

Which means, only the 1 numbers will stay in the result if both of them have 1's on the same position.